# Kill not killing process if exiting properly

Tags: bash, background-process

I have a simple bash script which I have written to simplify some work I am doing. All it needs to do is start one process, `process_1`, as a background process then start another, `process_2`. Once `process_2` is finished I then need to terminate `process_1`.

`process_1` starts a program which does not actually stop unless it receives the kill signal, or CTRL+C when I run it myself. The program is output into a file via `{program} {args} > output_file`

`process_2` can take an arbitrary amount of time depending on the arguments it is given.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Call this on exit to kill all background processes
function killJobs () {
    #Check process is still running before killing
    if kill -0 "$PID"; then
            kill $PID
    fi
}
```

...Check given arguments are valid...

```
#Start process_1
eval "./process_1 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3}" &
PID=$!

#Lay a trap to catch any exits from script
trap killJobs TERM INT

#Start process_2 - sleep for 5 seconds before and after
#Need space between process_1 and process_2 starting and stopping
sleep 5
eval "./process_2 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3} ${Arg4} 2> ${output_file}"
sleep 5

#Make sure background job is killed on exit
killJobs
```

I check `process_1` has been terminated by checking of its output file is still being updated after my script has ended.

If I run the script and then press CTRL+C the script is terminated and `process_1` is also killed, the output file is no longer updated.

If I let the script run to its completion without my intervention `process_2` and the script both terminate but when I check the output from `process_1` it is still being updated.

To check this I put an echo statement just after `process_1` is started and another within the if statement of `killJobs`, so it would only be echoed if `kill $PID` is called.

Doing this I can see that both ways of exiting start `process_1` and then also enter the if statement to kill it. Yet kill does not actually kill the process in the case of normal exit. No error messages are produced either.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but why use ```eval``` here?

Answer (score 1):

You're backgrounding the `eval` instead of `process_1`, which sets $! to the PID of the script itself, not to process_1. Change to:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Call this on exit to kill all background processes
function killJobs () {
    #Check process is still running before killing
    if kill -0 "$PID"; then
            kill $PID
    fi
}
...Check given arguments are valid...

#Start process_1
./process_1 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3} &
PID=$!

#Lay a trap to catch any exits from script
trap killJobs TERM INT

#Start process_2 - sleep for 5 seconds before and after
#Need space between process_1 and process_2 starting and stopping
sleep 5
./process_2 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3} ${Arg4} 2> ${output_file}
sleep 5

#Make sure background job is killed on exit
killJobs
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that. For me, `eval "./process_1 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3}" &` reproduces your bug, and both `eval "./process_1 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3} &"` and `./process_1 ${Arg1} ${Arg2} ${Arg3} &` don't, so probably our setups are different. What's your `bash --version` and `which bash`? Mine's `4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)` Alternatively, I'm using `tail -f` as a stand-in for your `process_1`. Does `process_1` start any background processes of its own?